# Yup validation of an array - values required only if array length is bigger than 1

Tags: javascript, reactjs, validation, formik, yup

I have 2 dropdowns in each row and I can dynamically add and remove rows apart form the first one. I would like to submit form if there is only one row (rendered from the beginning) and it is empty and **not** be able to submit if:

- value1 is selected without value 2

**or**

- a new row is added but has no value selected

I am using yup validation.

I have tried with checking the length with .test(), but this test run always after checking 'required'.

This is what I would like to have:

```
const validationSchema = yup.object({
values:
    yup.array()
        .of(
            yup.object({
                value1: yup.string().required(), // ONLY IF ARRAY LENGTH > 1
                value2: yup.string().required()// ONLY IF VALUE1 IS SELECTED
            })
        )});
```

Answer (score 3):

If I understand you correctly, then this should do.

```
const mySchema = yup.object({
  values: yup.array().of(
    yup.object({
      value1: yup
        .string()
        .test(
          "test-1",
          "error: required if array length > 1",
          (value, context) => {
            const [, values] = context.from;
            const {
              value: { values: arrayValues }
            } = values;
            // ONLY IF ARRAY LENGTH > 1
            if (arrayValues.length > 1) {
              // valid only if value is provided
              return !!value;
            }
          }
        ),
      value2: yup.string().when("value1", {
        // if value1 is provied, value2 should be provided too
        is: (value1) => !!value1,
        then: (value2) => value2.required()
      })
    })
  )
});
```

```
 // should pass
  console.log(
    mySchema.validateSync({
      values: [
        { value1: "1", value2: "2" },
        { value1: "1", value2: "2" }
      ]
    })
  );
  // ValidationError: error: required if array length > 1
  console.log(
    mySchema.validateSync({
      values: [{ value1: "1", value2: "2" }, { value2: "2" }]
    })
  );

  // ValidationError: values[1].value2 is a required field
  console.log(
    mySchema.validateSync({
      values: [{ value1: "1", value2: "2" }, { value1: "1" }]
    })
  );
```

The key thing here is to remove `.required()` and provide your own check in `test()` when the array meets your custom condition.

to access the parent value inside of `.test()`,  use `context.from`

```
const [parent1, parent2, ...rest] = context.from;
```

[Live Example](https://codesandbox.io/s/exciting-fire-6prkq?file=/src/index.js)

Comment: Thank you. 
Could you please explain me more the part with context.from? I don't know how to use the last line so that I don't get an error 
'Property 'from' does not exist on type 'TestContext<AnyObject>'.'